# Gatsby V3 does not create page in onCreatePage function after deletePage

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Recently I migrated my project from gatsby V2 to V3 and after migration, some of the code does not work as it supposed to.

A scenario which I was using and which I need to achieve right now:

1. I have different subfolders under the `/pages` folder, every
   subfolder has `index.js` files and is named uppercase
2. In `gatsby-node.js` file in `onCreatePage` function I delete page with `deletePage` function and create a new one with a different slug with `createPage` function.

my `gatsby-node.js` code:

```
export const onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { deletePage, createPage } = actions;

  const page_path = toLower(page.path);

  deletePage(page);

  if (page.componentPath === `${__dirname}/src/pages/HomePage/index.js`) {
    // create a new page but with '/' as path
    createPage({ ...page, path: '/' });
  } else if (page_path.match(/^\/account/)) {
    page.matchPath = '/account/*';

    // Create the new page.
    createPage({ ...page, path: page_path });
  } else if (
    page_path.match(/^\/kitchensink/) &&
    process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`
  ) {
    //pass
  } else {
    // create a new page but make slug all lowercase as page subfolders are named uppercase
    createPage({ ...page, path: page_path });
  }
};
```

After migration, this method deletes the page but does not create a new one, seems that `createPage` function does not work anymore or it has some issues. As a result, I do not get any pages as it was deleted, it does not appear in the `public` folder structure either.

Maybe I do not spot my mistake, tried many different things to solve the issue but did not work.

Is there any way to force gatsby URLs to be JUST lowercase?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved [Here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31055)